# Posição de um elemento na lista

Tags: haskell

Bem, eu tinha de fazer uma função que, dada uma lista e um número, retorne o elemento da lista que está nessa posição (o número).

Basicamente é a função já definida. O problema é que tenho de restringir a função no caso do número dado ser superior às posições existentes.

Tentei por um `where` mas dá erro. Posso colocar este `where`? Senão, em que situações posso usar `where`?

```
localiza:: [a] -> Int -> a

localiza [a] 0 = a
localiza (a:as) b  = localiza (as) (b-1) 
                       where b + 1 <= length(a)
```

Ocorre este erro:  `parse error on input 'where'`.

Comment: qual seria essa função que já é definida?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um pequeno código que atende aos seus propósitos, veja:

```
localiza :: [a] -> Int -> a
localiza x y
    | y > length x - 1 = error "Posição excede o tamanho da lista"
    | otherwise = head(drop y x)

main = do 
    let list = [1,2,3,4]
    print $ list -- Imprime a lista 
    print $ localiza list 3 -- Imprime o 4° elemento 0-index
    print $ list -- Imprime novamente a lista
```

**Explicando o código**

```
localiza x y
    | y > length x = error "Posição excede o tamanho da lista"
    | otherwise = head(drop y x)
```

Localiza recebe uma lista x e um valor inteiro y. Usamos [Guards](http://haskell.tailorfontela.com.br/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards) para fazer um controle de fluxo que diz o seguinte:

- Caso y seja maior que o tamanho da lista retorne um erro
- Caso contrário retorne o primeiro elemento da lista com y posições a menos (a lista original não é alterada)

No código `main` eu atribuo um valor à variável **list** usando a palavra chave **let**, utilizo a função localiza e em seguida imprimo a lista novamente só para mostrar que ela não foi alterada.

**Não precisa reinventar a roda**

Existe um operador que faz isso, o `!!`. Para usá-lo faça o seguinte:

```
[1,2,3,4]!!1 -- 2
```